# Configuring bridge network in kvm (debian wheezy 7.2)

Tags: debian, kvm, bridge

I am trying to run untangle 10 as a guest in kvm. My host system is debian 7.2

My problem is that I am unable to configure bridges/(virtual)NICS which are successfully identified by untangle. I would like to have two NICS in untangle. One for the internet connection and the other one for the internal network.

I already read several tutorials and how-to's and as far as I understood I have to configure network bridges.

I tried to configure them in /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports eth0
```

I also tried to configure them via virt-manager and I also tried to use macvtap.

In all three cases I was not able to establish a connection via untangle. Is there anything I am missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if iptables is active, we can give the following rules.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-out br0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in br0 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The bribge network interface
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

Comment: Your extra options `bridge_stp`, `_fd`, `_maxwait` aren't mentioned in the [interfaces(5) manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=interfaces&sektion=5&manpath=Debian+7.8+wheezy).  Where did you find out what they do?

Comment: This is an example where only one bridge is used and not needed stp